# Error en color en round_button.xml

Tags: java, android, material-design, color

Estoy colocando el radio a mis botones pero falla el color, no se pq se pone negro en vez de naranja como debería, el botón si está agarrando el radio como debe pero no agarra el color, ese es el único problema

**round_button.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/background_orange" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<!-- Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        style="@style/button"
        android:text="@string/button_login" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/round_button</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
        <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
        <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
        <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
        <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
        <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    
        <color name="black">#2A3235</color>
        <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
        <color name="background">#D0C1A9</color>
        <color name="background_orange">#8FDC7700</color>
        <color name="background_orange_light">#F18B13</color>
    </resources>
```

**Vista previa**

[image: activity_main.xml]

Comment: Te refieres a el botón que dice "LOG IN"?

Comment: Ese mismo, agarra los border pero no el color

Answer (score 0):

El color que debe tomar tu botón sería `background_orange` y este esta definido como:

```
<color name="background_orange">#8FDC7700</color>
```

y la configuración del botón es correcta tomando el shape que define este color, asegura que dentro de tu archivo `styles.xml` únicamente tengas un estilo llamado "button".

Pero el problema en este caso puede deberse a que estas configurando un "alpha" a tu color, te sugiero definas el color sin esta propiedad de esta forma:

```
  <color name="background_orange">#DC7700</color>
```

Comment: No funciona :(

Lo que hice fue crear un color nuevo como indicas sin alpha y colocarlo en el style para que lo agarre y nada

<color name="background_orange_button">#DC7700</color>

<item name="android:background">@drawable/round_button</item>

Se sigue viendo negro y sigo sin saber que sucede

Comment: Revisaste en styles.xml que tengas solo un estilo "button" ?

Comment: Por supuesto, y colocandolo de manera manual el background en el xml del activity_main tampoco funciona

Comment: Eso si es demasiado extraño, ve al menu en "Build"  y realiza un "Clean Project" y "Rebuild Project"

Comment: Solo deja cambiar el color de fondo con la propiedad "backgroundTint", pero si se la agrego junto con el estilo del "background" no hace nada, pero si quito el estilo si tiene el color pero sin el estilo

Comment: Me parece que hay otro estilo definido por ahí cambia el nombre del estilo en el boton   style="@style/estilobutton" y cambialo en styles.xml de button a estilobutton para probar, eso puede ser el problema

Comment: tampoco :( hay algo muy raro que sucede alli, cree un style como style_button y nada, tampoco agarra el color, habrá que investigar bien eso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127453/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-joel-guerrero).